# How To Utilize Inputs in a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks

I am using neural networks (keras in python) in order to forecast electrical demand for the next day. My model is working ok, however it is really struggling with weekends as electrical demand is lower on Saturday and Sundays. My data is half-hourly and the model takes in the previous 3 days data and the value of that hourly load from the exact same hour the previous week; and then makes a day ahead (48-step) prediction.

The reason I am using the value from the previous week as there is an extremely high autocorrelation between values and their week-before value.

> My question is how I should utilize my inputs for maximum prediction effectiveness?

One example of an idea that I had would be: given the previous week value, tweak that value using the previous 3-days data.

How can I use my input data to benefit what I'm trying to achieve here, and in general? What effect does changing the positions of the two input values, layers between them, etc., have?

My current model is the following:

[image]

where input_121 corresponds to the week before value.

Comment: If the relation between the current values and the ones one week ago is stronger than the one between the current ones and the last three days then maybe you should insert the last three days from the week before (instead of the last three days before the current point in time). Additionally you could give the model a feeling for the 'deviation' from these old values using the very recent ones: insert differences between current values and the ones a week before. Theoretically this should not change the performance as it is a linear operation...

Comment: but maybe it helps the optimization process (just a wild guess). You could also try other things like first applying a Kalman Filter to the very recent values and or tweak it using the values from one week ago to see the difference between where the very recent values 'should be' and where they 'actually are' (i.e. is power consumption higher than expected or lower than expected right now?)

Comment: What about simply adding dummies for a weekday?

Comment: @Tim I tried that, but I still have the problem of how to implement that information into the neural network? Thanks

Comment: I'd go for something like: dense sub-network over a matrix of dummies and the result concatenated to `concatenate_106` .